# Error getting data from Graphite 500 Internal Server Error (Intermittent)

Tags: graphite, http-status-code-500

I need some help tracking down a sporadic http status 500 internal server error when using Graphite.

The server is running on Ubuntu 16.04, Graphite version 0.9.15.

```
10.0.0.10 - - [09/Jul/2017:08:07:14 -0500] "GET /render?from=-3minute&target=aliasByNode%28divideSeries%28hosts.Test.metric1.mean%2C+hosts.Test.metric2.mean%29%2C+1%29&format=json HTTP/1.1" 500 1237 "-" "python-requests/2.7.0 CPython/2.7.12 Linux/4.4.0-62-generic"
```

The same request works again without any modification.

Comment: You need to run that render request on the separate browser tab - then you will get an exact error message from Graphite and find what's going on.

Comment: @deniszh not sure what you mean exactly, can you elaborate.  When I put the render request in the browser it succeeds.  Are you saying that had it failed in the browser it would have showed the error?  Does it have to be a localhost request to see the error?

Comment: If this request suceeds 100% of time - then it's no use, indeed. You just need to try until you get error. Not sure what you mean when asking about "locahost request", though. You need to run render queue on your Graphite server. For example, when I try your query above on my Graphite I have an instant error - 
`curl "https://<MYGRAPHITESERVER>/render?from=-3minute&target=aliasByNode(divideSeries(hosts.Test.metric1.mean,+hosts.Test.metric2.mean),+1)&format=json"
...
ValueError: divideSeries second argument must reference exactly 1 series`

Comment: @deniszh by localhost I meant running it from the server but I see what you mean.  Since it does succeed on a subsequent attempt it's been hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: can you provide uwsgi and nginx/apache log? Maybe it just timedout, while waiting for available uwsgi? Configuration of nginx/apache and uwsgi would be handful.

Comment: @kwarunek I upgraded today from version 0.9.15 to 1.0.2 and from apache to nginx, I will have to see if it happens again.